# How to graph $|x|+|y|\le1$?

Tags: inequality, graphing-functions

What should be the approach to draw the graph of the above inequality with modulus? Should I need to begin like this?
$$|y| = 1 - |x|$$

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has been discussed here before, with equality. $|x|+|y|=1$ is a diamond, and the less-than-1 part is the interior of that diamond.

Comment: I would try to separate the cases: $x \geq 0$,$y \geq 0$ and so on.

Answer (score 1):

It is:
$$
\begin{cases}
y\ge 0\\
y\le1-|x|
\end{cases}
\quad \land \quad
\begin{cases}
y< 0\\
y\ge|x|-1
\end{cases}
$$
so it is a square with vertices: $(1,0)$,$(0,1)$,$(-1,0)$,$(0,-1)$